# Is there a function for closing a mysql prepared statement with PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

In mysqli prepared statements there is[`mysqli_stmt::close()`](http://php.net/mysqli_stmt.close) (Closes a prepared statement):

```
$stmt->close();
```

I have searched php.net and the web and cannot find an alternative for PDO.

Is this possible?

And what are the benefits of using it at the end of each of your scripts?

I understand that,

```
$connection = null;
```

closes the connection to mysql, but what about closing the query?

Comment: Close a query? Where do you open a query?

Comment: r u talking about 'mysql_free_result()' http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-free-result.php

Comment: `mysqli::close` - Closes a previously opened database connection

Comment: diEcho, thats both not PDO you're talking about. Read the question more properly.

Comment: @halfdan i know that both are not `PDO` i m just asking to the user that what exactly he want...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To free the result set you can apply basic PHP way.

If you are returning the results with [`PDOStatement::fetchAll()`](http://php.net/PDOStatement.fetchAll) then you would need to `unset()` the variable to clear it:

```
$variable = $stmt->fetchAll();

unset($variable);
// or:
$variable = null;
```

Or [`PDOStatement::closeCursor()`](http://php.net/PDOStatement.closeCursor) (*Closes the cursor, enabling the statement to be executed again.*) may be helpful:

```
$success = $stmt->closeCursor();
```

Comment: Ye I meant what was in your comment, what is the mysqli_free_result equivelant in PDO?