# MySQL(i) "Too many connections" what to do?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm writing a hugh MySQLi/PHP application and experience problems with my database, it seems that there are too many connections open (250) after running for a couple of hours.

I'm using a very fast external database server in my network. I'm reaching like 1000 questions per second and the server does not seem impressed (the load is close to 0).

In my application the MySQLi link is closed by the destructor of the database class (this seems to work properly).

I'm using prepared statements and have also a couple of daemons running with infinite while loops and some queries inside it (the loops are delayed with `usleep()` to prevent overuse and I have to notice that `mysqli_connect()` is only called once starting the daemon).

But it seems that I never close my prepared statements with `stmt->close()`. Under query stats in my database I can see that the number of `stmt->close()` questions is equal to the number of `stmt->execute()`. So can this be the problem and when do I have to close my stmt for example? I don't know where to find a solution for this problem.

**Software versions**

PHP 5.5 under CentOS 6.5 with MySQL 5.6

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience with PHP PDO, but this might be helpful as a start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685879/is-there-a-function-for-closing-a-mysql-prepared-statement-with-pdo

Comment: What platform? What web server software? What version of php?

Comment: @oliakaoil I dont use PDO, I use PHP MySQLi. But I will read your suggestion.

Comment: The question is how long scripts with usleep are executed. If they run 30 minutes, and you call them too many in a time they can use many connections. Other question is what's the traffic on your site and if "Too many connections" is somehow connected to users actions(many users visit your site) or by as you called deamons. I think the problem is with your daemons - you launch them and maybe never finish the ones you started previously so after some time you reach maximum connections limit

Comment: @OllieJones PHP 5.5 under CentOS 6.5 with MySQL 5.6

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Error "Too many connections"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202322/mysql-error-too-many-connections)

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek The scripts run as daemon (so they run for ever until I stop it). The usleep is always bigger then 50000 so that are less that 20 simple select queries per second.

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek it's not a website with traffic. It's more like a private application with a backend wich will be used by less then 5 users. So there isn't any traffic at all.

Comment: @ArekvanSchaijk How many deamons are launched? Do you use cron to run those daemons or another scripts?

Comment: just a quick one but are you closing your connections ? or another thing what are you setting for your mysql wait_timeout  and interactive_timeout inside your my.cnf ?

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek There are about 4-5 daemons running that produce less then 20 queries apiece per second. If I'm right this are Unix Daemons that run my script in their own process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some things to try:

First: in your infinite-loop daemon processes: close your connections before sleeping and open them again upon waking. Don't try to hold database connections open for a long time. There's all kinds of timeout logic in the client-server connection that may activate when you don't want it to and therefore give you unpredictable failures. Opening connections, using them, then closing them will avoid that.

Second: try using so-called persistent connections.  In `mysqli` you can prepend `p:` to your hostname to do this.  Read this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.persistconns.php

Third: It is good practice to `close()` your prepared statements explicitly when you're done with them, and to `reset()` them between uses if you reuse them. The mysqli dtor is supposed to do this automatically, but it's still good practice

Fourth: You may want to configure your Apache or ngnix server software to spawn fewer instances and threads.  These instances and/or threads are serially resuable resources, and Linux's TCP stack does a good job of queueing up connect requests for them. This should reduce the number of connections MySQL needs to handle.

Fifth: Do you need to change you MySQL's configuration to allow more than 250 connections? If you're loadbalancing your web traffic to lots of web servers, you may need to do that.

Congratulations on getting a lot of traffic! Now for some real fun. bwahahaha.

Comment: I've found my mistake in a long polling ajax call. This call occurred every pageview in my back-end and had no endtime unless there was data to return :-) So by walking trough my back-end it was generating a lot of endless processes (I'm stupid I know lol).

Comment: I have lot of code rewritten based on your answer. For example: My daemons reconnect every 30 seconds so they doesn't hold the connection open for a long time anymore and I'm using `stmt->close()` and `stmt->reset()` now. The problem seems to be solved now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: This kind of thing (different in details, same in general principles) happens in every web app that scales up. Not stupid at all. It's hard to teach this in school.