# Use same mysqli prepared statement for different queries?

Tags: mysql, php, prepared-statement, mysqli

Throughout some testings; a little question popped up. When I usually code database updates; I usually do this via callbacks which I code in PHP; to which I simply pass a given [mysqli connection object](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) as function argument. Executing all queries of for example three queries across the same single connection proved to be much faster than if closing and reopening a DB connection for each query of a given query sequence. This also works easily with SQL transactions, the connection can be passed along to callbacks without any issues.

My question is; can you also do this with [prepared statement objects](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-stmt) ? What I mean is, considering we successfully established a `$conn` object, representing the mysqli connection, is stuff like this legit? :

```
function select_users( $users_id, $stmt ) {

  $sql = "SELECT username FROM users where ID = ?";

  mysqli_stmt_prepare( $stmt, $sql );
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param( $stmt, "i", $users_id );
  mysqli_stmt_execute( $stmt );

  return mysqli_stmt_get_result( $stmt );

}

function select_labels( $artist, $stmt ) {

  $sql = "SELECT label FROM labels where artist = ?";

  mysqli_stmt_prepare( $stmt, $sql );
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param( $stmt, "s", $artist );
  mysqli_stmt_execute( $stmt );

  return mysqli_stmt_get_result( $stmt );

}

$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init( $conn );

$users = select_users( 1, $stmt );
$rappers = select_labels( "rapperxyz", $stmt );
```

or is it bad practice; and you should rather use:

```
$stmt_users = mysqli_stmt_init( $conn );
$stmt_rappers = mysqli_stmt_init( $conn );

$users = select_users( 1, $stmt_users );
$rappers = select_labels( "rapperxyz", $stmt_rappers );
```

During the testing; I noticed that the method by using a single statement object passed along callbacks works for server calls where I call like 4 not too complicated DB queries via the 4 according callbacks in a row.

When I however do a server call with like 10 different queries, sometimes (yes, only sometimes; for pretty much the same data used across the different executions; so this seems to be weird behavior to me) I get the error `"Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now"` and some other weird errors I've never experienced, like the amount of variables not matching the amount of parameters; although they prefectly do after checking them all. The only way to fix this I found after some research was indeed by using different statement objects for each callback. So, I just wondered; should you actually ALWAYS use ONE prepared statement object for ONE query, which you then may execute N times in a row?

Comment: I hope you are not talking about AJAX "callbacks".

Comment: You mean an AJAX request for every single DB operation ? Nono, the callbacks are rather functions declared as private; which are then called sequentially in a wrapper function declared as public of the same class; so THAT wrapper function is the one calling these callbacks all in a row / the same AJAX. Makes sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

The "commands out of sync" error is because MySQL protocol is not like http. You can't send requests any time you want. There is state on the server-side (i.e. mysqld) that is expecting a certain sequence of requests. This is what's known as a stateful protocol.

Compare with a protocol like ftp. You can do an `ls` in an ftp client, but the list of files you get back depends on the current working directory. If you were sharing that ftp client connection among multiple functions in your app, you don't know that another function hasn't changed the working directory. So you can't be sure the file list you get from `ls` represents the directory you thought you were in.

In MySQL too, there's state on the server-side. You can only have one transaction open at a time. You can only have one query executing at a time. The MySQL client does not allow you to execute a new query where there are still rows to be fetched from an in-progress query. See [Commands out of sync](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commands-out-of-sync.html) in the MySQL doc on common errors.

So if you pass your statement handle around to some callback functions, how can that function know it's safe to execute the statement?

IMO, the only safe way to use a statement is to use it immediately.

Comment: Awesome and perfectly understandable explanation; makes total sense actually, cheers mate!

Comment: Which consequently means; if you do it in procedural way in PHP; initiate a new statement object via ```mysqli_stmt_init( $conn )``` for each SQL query, and after having it executed N times, close that stmt object via ```mysqli_stmt_close( $stmt )```; and so for every SQL query you might want to execute N times; correct? Just to be sure; and thanks again!

Comment: Yep, that's what I do. In theory, it is possible to have multiple statements prepared, but coordinating their use across objects and callbacks etc. is more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: Hi again, I'm currently switching from mysqli to PDO in PHP (indeed somewhat easier) and I could more or less solve all of the transitions from my previous code to the PDO API; but I'm precisely missing what we've discussed here: An alias to `mysqli_stmt_close()`. I know I'm not the only one with [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32809742/close-pdo-statement), but I thought of bringing it up here for a clear context. I could find [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.closecursor.php), but that keeps it in memory. Is that good enough, or is there a better way in PDO?

Comment: If you have a prepared query and you were fetching results in unbuffered mode, and want to execute the query again before you have fetched all results, I think you would have to use `closeCursor()`. But that's a very specific case. Most of the time, you can forget about it, and as your PHP request is cleaned up, it'll close all cursors and connections automatically.